# Irobot create usb to serial connection not working

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I connected to the irobot create using a USB to serial cable (DB9) then i manually connected in the serial cable wires into the irobot create DB25 serial port

When i am charging the irobot create it sends back gibberish status messages over serial, i am monitoring what it says through hyper-terminal. I checked the baud rate ect...

I suspect the irobot-create is using TTL logic levels for its serial?
Someone told be the irobot create cant use standard usb to serial cables, and need ttl usb to to serial cables.

Has anyone got the create working using custom built cables ( i don't have the irobot create serial cable)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63807/irobot-create-usb-to-serial-connection-not-working/) by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 418 on 2013-05-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need a USB to FDTI serial cable at TTL logic levels or it wont work

---

Originally posted by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) with karma: 418 on 2013-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0